# DNN default skin is mobile compatible

Tags: dotnetnuke

I m building a site in DNN 6.1 , it is in construction mode. I m using community edition
I want to know that is DNN 6.1 default skin is mobile compatible ?

Thankx and Regards

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer. No.

More complex answer, sure, everything is mobile compatible, but it won't be mobile friendly.